# Multiple slideshows on a page

Tags: javascript, views

On the home page of a site I want to list each node as an individual slideshow. Each node shown will be of the same content type. I am using views slideshow and panels if it helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "individual slideshow"?  Views Slideshow takes a series of nodes and turns them into one slideshow.  So I don't know what an "individual slideshow" would be in this context.

Comment: @PatrickKenny Lets say I have a content type called projects. Each project contains a series of images to be shown in a slideshow format. on a page I want to show:

Project 1 slideshow
Project 2 slideshow
Project 3 slideshow
etc

Comment: Ok, then you should use Field Slideshow (which does slideshows for a multi-value field of a single node) or a similar module, not Views Slideshow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to achieve this, You have to use views along with [Scrollable Content](https://drupal.org/project/scrollable_content)

It provides a scrolling functionality for your content. Scrollable Content will give you a nice content slider preview of your site's nodes, and provides some display options.

> The basic use is via blocks page, you'll find a block called
>   "Scrollable Content" and if you want more control & you know how to
>   use Views, you should use the Views style for Scrollable Content.

or you can check [Scrollable Views](https://drupal.org/project/scrollable) , I'm using this in my website, but it no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

This has been achieved using the Fields Slideshow module.

https://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow

In views you can then select the image format for the field as slideshow, similar to colorbox.

[image]

This seems to be working fine for me but I am open to other suggestions

Comment: Could you please add a link and explanation why this module and how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem while having multiple views slideshow block from same view on same page the following link may help

http://crudpixel.com/content/drupal-multiple-slideshow-blocks-same-view-same-page

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to create extra field and add some node images to that field and after that you can call a function from home page and in that function you have to write

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
  $query->join('field_data_field_slider_actve', 'sa', 'sa.entity_id = n.nid');  
  $query->fields('n', array('nid'));
  $query->range(0, 5);
  $query->condition('n.type', 'home_slider');


  $results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```